# if $AX = 0 \Rightarrow BX = 0$, prove that $B = CA$ for some $C$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices of $m\times n$ and $k \times n$, respectively, such that if $AX = 0$ for a certain column $X$ , then $BX = 0$. Prove that $B = CA$, where $C$ is matrix of size $k \times m$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that all entries of matrices $A$ and $B$ are real numbers.
Let $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ be the rows of matrix $A$, $b_1,\ldots,b_m$ be the rows of matrix $B$.

Let $L(A)$ and $L(B)$ be subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ generated by the rows of matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Then
$$
L(A)^\perp=\{X\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid AX=0\},\qquad
L(B)^\perp=\{X\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid BX=0\}.
$$
By the condition $L(A)^\perp\subset L(B)^\perp$. Then $L(B)\subset L(A)$. This means that each element $b_i$ is expressed through $a_1,\ldots,a_k$. Now it's easy to figure out how to construct the matrix $C$.

Comment: Others can search answerers for percentages of questions they answered, that are subsequently closed or deleted (and with deletion of a question, the answer(s) are deleted, too).  Also, FYI, please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|133.6622).  So please consider yourself informed.